# How to output state into multiple text in script of Linux?

Tags: linux, iostat

I have multiple servers of Linux, where I need to test the performance of my program, here I want to output the system state when running programs. In script of linux, I use following to output:

```
top -b -d 5 > System.txt
iostat -d 8 > IO.txt
```

But unfortunately, only the **system.txt** can be produced, but there is no the **IO.txt** file, so that need to add some thing in script to make these two file exist together?

Answer (score 0):

Use iostat command like this :-
iostat -d 8 1 > IO.txt.

In this 1 means the limit, how many time do you want to run the command get the result.